# Calculate field tool doesn't stop running because of codeblock in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator

I am running the following model, which seems to work and populate the added field that I want, but the final calculate field doesn't stop running even though it seemed to do what it should. The point shapefile has 48,000 rows. Essentially I am seeing if !Yield! is not more than 2 standard deviations away from the !Yield! mean. If it is within the 2 standard deviations then return 1 else return 2 into the column.

> Value = mean of the yield
>
> Value2 = standard deviation of the yield.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1.

[image: Model]

[image: Calc_field inputs]

Comment: The iteration field is over a folder that will go through 20+ shapefiles. I am only trying to run this model right now with one shapefile in that folder.

Comment: You need to make both outputs of the Get Field value tools *preconditions* of the Calculate Field tool, i.e. they need to have been computed first before you attempt the field calculation. Currently whats stopping the logic going down the add field first before the summary branch? Nothing...

Comment: Setting the values passed to the field calculator as preconditions did the trick! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

With help I figured it out. I set the values passed to the field calculator as preconditions. Thanks for the advice @Hornbydd.

[image: correct model]